# What languages are new programmer friendly?

Tags: programming-languages

What languages are new programmer friendly?  My friend is a game designer who knows very little about programming but wants to program his old stuff.  What is a good language to start him off in.  Also what language should he finally aim for?

Answer (score 2):

Again a "It depends" answer, but maybe this [StackExchange resource](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-are-some-good-resources-for-getting-a-beginner-started-in-developing-games) helps.

Comment: This has been asked many times before and continues to be closed regularly.  Thanks for pointing to a resource on SE.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a popular language for first time programmers, and features a popular platform for creating games:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame

Your friend will probably want to learn C++ at some point though.

Comment: +1 Starting with Python and seeing how his concepts translate into high level code etc. and therefore learning the basics is a good approach to get started quickly. He can start worrying about memory allocation and pointers at a later stage, when he actually **knows** how his concepts work in code.

Answer (score 1):

C# and Delphi...I saw many new programmers who were comfortable with these two languages.

Comment: I was about to nerd rage on you for calling them 'toy' languages. Then I read it again.. :p

Comment: My first programming language was delphi and i don't  regret it.
It's not too hard to learn, really intuitive, has a very clean syntax and a great community.

Answer (score 1):

Try Blitz3D
http://www.blitzbasic.com/Products/blitz3d.php

Some of my students with basic knowledge in programming succeeded in creating awesome games (2d shooters, logical, puzzles, arcade, etc) in it in short period of time. It's simple and game-dev oriented, easy to learn and to get started quickly.

Answer (score 0):

http://tryruby.org/

just try it :)